# Multiple property rules

Tags: opa, rego

I must be missing the right words because I can not find how to create a rule that uses multiple properties of an object. I am trying to validate that "bob" has the action and resource in his list of endpoints.

The data looks like this:

```
"clientaccount_endpoints": [
    {
        "ClientId": "Bob",
        "Endpoints": [
            {
                "Action": "GET",
                "Resource": "employee",
                "Tenantable": true
            }]}]}
```

The input is this:

```
{
    "clientaccount": "bob",
    "action": "GET",
    "resource": "employee"
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
clientaccount_entitled {
    some i
    data.clientaccount_endpoints[i].ClientId == input.clientaccount
    data.clientaccount_endpoints[i].Action == input.action
    data.clientaccount_endpoints[i].Resource == input.resource
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there but have a couple issues:

(1) Data in rego is case-sensitive; `bob` does not match `Bob`.

(2) Your paths are not correct--try this:

```
clientaccount_entitled {
    some i,j
    data.clientaccount_endpoints[i].ClientId == input.clientaccount
    data.clientaccount_endpoints[i].Endpoints[j].Action == input.action
    data.clientaccount_endpoints[i].Endpoints[j].Resource == input.resource
}
```